# Add span to table row depending on if (Symfony - Twig - Vue)

Tags: symfony, vue.js, twig

I'm learning Vue and I'm trying to add it to an existing Symfony 3.4 project.

I have a twig with this content (it's not reactive):

```
<td><span class="{% if entity.isExecuting %}blink_me fa fa-cog{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
```

I have downloaded npm and installed Vue using npm, then I added Vue in the .twig file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```

In the same twig file I'm trying to create a new Vue application (I guess that's the right place) but I can't figure out how to add the fa fa-cog if entity.isExecuting is true.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    const vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#vapp',
        data: { 
            display: 'redbox' 
            },
        template: '<span class="blink_me fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
        computed: {
            running: function() {
                if (Entity.isExecuting) {
                    return '<span class="blink_me fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The variable entity.isExecuting comes from the twig:

```
<tbody>
    {% for entity in application.process %}
```

Would you recommend any examples for this?
Thanks alot.

Update: I've figured I had to install Encore first, manually, since I'm not using Symfony Flex. I did all the configuration from the Symfony Docs, now I can see that I have Vue enabled in the page.

Comment: What is `Entity.isExecuting`? A variable from where?

Comment: have you checked: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes ?

Comment: @acdcjunior entity.isExecuting comes from the for clause in the twig, and it's related with a php class that changes that value when it lists all the processes. What I've received is that the span is being added to all the process, not just the ones that are really being executed.